# How to return control of flow to a for loop?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, for-loop

I'm trying to code a loop to re execute a block of code 3 times. At the moment the code starts and executes once but doesn't repeat as intended with using the `for` loop.

I've set a break point on the `for` loop and it only goes through the loop once.

```
    private async void startBtn_Tap(object sender, System.Windows.Input.GestureEventArgs e)
    {
        int i;
        int roundMax = 3;

         for (i = 1; i <= roundMax; i++)
         {
                //delay stop watch start to allow time to get ready.
                TimeSpan time = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1);
                await System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Delay(time);


                //set text box editing to false to prevent illegal input.
                wrkTbx.IsEnabled = false;
                restTbx.IsEnabled = false;
                roundSlider.IsEnabled = false;
                roundsTbx.IsEnabled = false;

                StopGoCvs.Background = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Green);
                //startSoundElmt.Play();
                // set up the timer
                myTimer = new DispatcherTimer();
                myTimer.Interval = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 0, 0, 1);

                myTimer.Tick += myTimer_Tick;

                // start both timers
                myTimer.Start();
                myStopwatch.Start();



        }

    }
```

Comment: Have you wrapped the startBtn_Tap implementation in a try/catch to see if an unhandled exception is occurring?

Comment: Could you share exactly at which line you placed the breakpoint?

Comment: @julealgon ,I put the breakpoint on the same line as the for loop.

Comment: The code you posted will execute the loop three times. So if your loop isn't, then you posted something different from your actual code. Also, if you could explain why you are a) wanting to execute that code three times, and b) why you only subscribe to the myTimer.Tick event _after_ you've started the timer, that would be helpful. On the face of it, the entire method just makes no sense. Three 1ms timers, starting the same Stopwatch three times, setting the same background three times, it's just plain weird.

Comment: @PeterDuniho the code within the loop calls the timer_tick and in turn calls an interval timer method which is why I suspect the timer isn't looping as the control of flow is still in one of these methods? a)The reason for executing three times is because it is an interval timer so each execution is a one round ie, 3 rounds. b)The starting the timer_tick after starting the timer was a mistake on my part. I'm gong to post the other two linked methods now in my question, timer_tick and intervalMethod.

Comment: @BrianJ: your description still doesn't match the code you've included here. There's no call to "timer_tick" in the loop, just a line subscribing the method "myTimer_Tick" to the newly-created Timer instance. If you want something to execute three times, with a delay in between, then you can either do a loop in a different thread (not the main GUI thread) where you call Thread.Sleep() for the delay instead of using a timer, or you can use the System.Threading.Timer class which allows you to create a non-repeating timer, and then have the first two timer invocations start the next timer.

Comment: @PeterDuniho I'm still a bit confused as what I'm doing wrong here, currently if I enter values for work and rest. eg 2 seconds 3 seconds, the timer will run for 5 seonds then stop which is the functionality I require. The problem I'm having is getting this execution to loop for a number of iterations. Could you explain your answer better with a code example that I may be able to interpret better.

Comment: I assume by "work" and "rest" you mean values in the "wkrTbx" and "restTbx" controls seen in your updated code. But you don't show any code that actually _uses_ those values. So again, your posted code is not consistent with your comments. That said, you've added a call to Task.Delay() here, which IMHO is on the right track. Seems to me you should be able to just get rid of all the timer-related code (second half of the for loop), insert the code you want to do actual work, and that should take care of it. If you want better advice than that, post a proper concise-but-complete code example.

Comment: @PeterDuniho is there some where I can post the code so that you can see? I don't want post a full class source in the question.

Comment: Definitely do not post the full source. Definitely _do_ create a new code example that is the least amount of code required to reproduce the problem. And post that here. If you've gotten the code example simple enough, it will be small enough to post here. If it's too big, then you need to make it simpler. If you think you can't, then you're asking too big a question in the first place and should break the question into smaller, more manageable pieces.

Comment: Valid comment, I'm working on it as we speak.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this is a logical issue, and I suspect it exits the for loop at some point, Assumming you're using Visual Studio, I would use Breakpoints at every steps and run the program to see where it fails, you may be missing a return or else somewhere